# wxpython closing application with thread

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython

Hi guys i have a little trouble.
I finished my program which check if exists a new revision on bitbucket.
All is fine except when i close my application and the thread is still running, the program can be seen in task manager.
Code of EVT_CLOSE is the following:

```
    def on_close(self, event):
    if self._thread is not None and self._thread.isAlive():
        self._thread.interrupt.set()
    self.Destroy()
    event.Skip()
```

Thread is running like deamon.

What's wrong?

EDIT:
i understund and i tried to do join() method on the thread.
But i doesn't work.

```
    def on_close(self, event):
if self._thread is not None and self._thread.isAlive():
    self._thread.join()
    self._thread.interrupt.set()
self.Destroy()
event.Skip()
```

And:

```
        def on_close(self, event):
if self._thread is not None and self._thread.isAlive():
    self._thread.join(10)
    self._thread.interrupt.set()
self.Destroy()
event.Skip()
```

Answer (score 0):

In you close event handler, you need to have it end the thread or wait for the thread to end. Normally you do that by using the thread's join() method. If the thread is opening another process and that process is taking a long time, then you might want to try killing the process that's running so that the thread can return.